# Is there any secured way to connect to a sql mdf file database?

Tags: sql-server, connection-string

I want to connect my project (asp.net forms app) to a database using only a `.mdf` file.

Is there any secured way to connect to a SQL Server `.mdf` database file with user and password?

If I'll publicate my application in a public server then there will be safe?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You're going to expose SQL server to the public internet? Enjoy having your server totally destroyed...

Comment: But the authentication database (databaseXXX.mdf) is located within the App_Data folder by default isnt 'it?

Comment: `.mdf` = SQL Server - you will need a **SQL Server** instance - one way or another - to use this data.

Comment: I don't agree, I stopped all sql services and the authentication still works... I created a test project, I stopped all services, Execute asp.net configuration, creater users and run the project and logon without any problem...

Comment: Then something is confused somewhere.  The only way to access a SQL Server database is through the database engine.  That means that at least the Sql Server service has to be running.  You could potentially read the data out of a `.mdf` by using a hex editor but it wouldn't be easy.

Comment: Try yourself!  Stop all SqlServices, Create a asp.net form project empty, run the asp.net configuration (in WebSite menu), add some users and try authenticate in the authen form (the default template has one..)